# A captivating and riveting java socket multithreading fandango

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets

Greetings and salutations,

I have two Android apps: one is the server and one is the client. The server receives strings from two or more clients. The server tests collision of input (eg inputs received within 1 ms or whatever). Once a client establishes a connection with the server, the server instantiates a client object that runs a while-true thread which facilitates input reception.

I believe that with OS time-sharing of the CPU, threads alternate their execution. This is a problem since I need to know if two InputStreams send messages within a ms or two of each other. How may I allow this?

```
public void run() {
  while (true) {
    try {
      if (input.ready()) {
      String s = input.readLine();
          //do stuff, like comparing socket inputs
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you will find the bigger problem is that the network layer alone will introduce variability in timing in the order of many milliseconds (just look at the range of times when running ping), such that even if the clients all send at the exact same moment you will find that they will often all arrive at times with a delta larger than a few milliseconds. You will also likely run into other timing issues related to the handling of incoming network data depending on the radio hardware, and kernel configuration that sit between the VM and the physical network, on both the sender and receiver. My point is that detecting collision with the timing of a few ms is probably not possible.

I'd suggest you send a timestamp with the message from the client so that it doesn't matter when it processes. To make it even more accurate you can add some simple time synchronization to the startup of your protocol to find the delta between the client and server device clocks.

If the goal is to just know which client sent data first, then you can just assume the blocked input.readline() that returns first is the one that sent data first, given data of similar length and similar ping latency for each client. This will under normal conditions be correct.  To deal with variable length data and a number of other issues related to the physical network a good tweak would be to do a byte read rather than a whole line, which gives you a better approximation of who arrived first as opposed to which client is able to send the whole line faster.